# Laravel relation with custom join condition

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-9

I received quite strange database to work with and I'm trying to create relation on model `Invoice` like below:

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Order::class, Shipment::class,
        'id',
        'id',
        DB::raw('-order_id'),
        Shipment::COL_ORDER_ID
    );
}
```

but it gives me the error `array_key_exists(): Argument #1 ($key) must be a valid array offset type`.
Of course the problem is in the `DB::raw` part... As you may have guessed I'm trying to create join condition like `-Invoice.order_id = Shipment.id` or `ABS(Invoice.order_id) = Shpment.id` will be fine too because only order_id on the Invoice needs to be converted into positive number.

Any ideas to get it to work with minimal additional code as possible? Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Why do you have a dash in raw()?

Comment: its a minus sign (order_id is a negative number so minus is for turning it into positive one)